# how to change the options' view in react select component?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

[image]

I want "Assigned" or selected item to be styled differently and positioned on the top of the options, not on the input field. How can it be achieved in react-select?

Comment: may be #css / #styling ...

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps ,
in react select  there is a value field you can use that state variable name to style
it .